# How Android APP bundles support different minSdkVersion

Tags: android, bundles

My Android APP has a minimum SDK 16. Recently, I want to update the Admob library to the latest version, it requires minimum SDK 19. If I publish the APP bundles with minSdk 19 to Google Play, it will replace the APP bundles with minSdk 16 completely. Then all users under API level 19 will upgrade to a very early version, which causes a lot of crashes. Several years ago, we could publish multiple APKs, and target different API levels by version code. How can I do the same thing with APP bundles?

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.6.0'
}
```

Comment: In the google play store console you can keep the existing version in the new release, so you will have a realse with two versions: the old one with minSdk16 and the new one with the minSdk 19

Comment: If I upload bundles with minSdk 19, play console told me it will replace minSdk 16. I can't find how to keep the exisitng version.

Comment: When you click on create release you will find the section to import the new vesion bundle, and in the below, the section of the old version, in the same line there is a button called "include", after click on it, the old version will move to the included section.

Comment: Thank you! I found it. The "Include" looks like a text, not a button.